# Extending Magento REST API V2 breaks existing API

Tags: orders, api, rest-api, extend

I am trying to extend the Magento CE (version 1.8.1.0) REST API V2 for orders. I want to customize the original order query so that the response includes an additional attribute "multifees".

Everything works fine but it seems that the original order API /orders/:order_id no longer exists (returns HTTP 404) once my module is active.

I want to keep the original order API untouched and add my own order API.

I suspect something is incorrect with api2.xml but I really cannot tell where it makes the original order route disappear:

```
<config>
<api2>
    <resource_groups>
        <base translate="title" module="MyCompany_Base">
            <title>MyCompany Order API</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        </base>
    </resource_groups>
    <resources>
        <order translate="title" module="MyCompany_Base">
            <group>base</group>
            <model>base/api2_order</model>
            <title>Order with Extra Fees</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <privileges>
                <admin>
                    <retrieve>1</retrieve>
                </admin>
            </privileges>
            <attributes translate="entity_id increment_id created_at status shipping_description _payment_method base_currency_code store_currency_code store_name remote_ip store_to_order_rate subtotal subtotal_incl_tax discount_amount base_grand_total grand_total shipping_amount shipping_tax_amount shipping_incl_tax tax_amount _tax_name _tax_rate coupon_code base_discount_amount base_subtotal base_shipping_amount base_shipping_tax_amount base_tax_amount total_paid base_total_paid total_refunded base_total_refunded base_subtotal_incl_tax base_total_due total_due shipping_discount_amount base_shipping_discount_amount discount_description customer_balance_amount base_customer_balance_amount base_customer_balance_amount _gift_message _order_comments customer_id multifees" module="MyCompany_Base">
                <entity_id>Order ID (internal)</entity_id>
                <increment_id>Order ID</increment_id>
                <created_at>Order Date</created_at>
                <status>Order Status</status>
                <shipping_description>Shipping Method</shipping_description>
                <_payment_method>Payment Method</_payment_method>
                <base_currency_code>Base Currency</base_currency_code>
                <store_currency_code>Order Currency</store_currency_code>
                <store_name>Store Name</store_name>
                <remote_ip>Placed from IP</remote_ip>
                <store_to_order_rate>Store Currency to Order Currency Rate</store_to_order_rate>
                <subtotal>Subtotal</subtotal>
                <subtotal_incl_tax>Subtotal Including Tax</subtotal_incl_tax>
                <discount_amount>Discount</discount_amount>
                <base_grand_total>Grand Total to Be Charged</base_grand_total>
                <grand_total>Grand Total</grand_total>
                <shipping_amount>Shipping Amount</shipping_amount>
                <shipping_tax_amount>Shipping Including Tax</shipping_tax_amount>
                <shipping_incl_tax>Shipping Tax</shipping_incl_tax>
                <tax_amount>Tax Amount</tax_amount>
                <_tax_name>Tax Name</_tax_name>
                <_tax_rate>Tax Rate</_tax_rate>
                <coupon_code>Coupon Code</coupon_code>
                <base_discount_amount>Base Discount</base_discount_amount>
                <base_subtotal>Base Subtotal</base_subtotal>
                <base_shipping_amount>Base Shipping</base_shipping_amount>
                <base_shipping_tax_amount>Base Shipping Tax</base_shipping_tax_amount>
                <base_tax_amount>Base Tax Amount</base_tax_amount>
                <total_paid>Total Paid</total_paid>
                <base_total_paid>Base Total Paid</base_total_paid>
                <total_refunded>Total Refunded</total_refunded>
                <base_total_refunded>Base Total Refunded</base_total_refunded>
                <base_subtotal_incl_tax>Base Subtotal Including Tax</base_subtotal_incl_tax>
                <base_total_due>Base Total Due</base_total_due>
                <total_due>Total Due</total_due>
                <shipping_discount_amount>Shipping Discount</shipping_discount_amount>
                <base_shipping_discount_amount>Base Shipping Discount</base_shipping_discount_amount>
                <discount_description>Discount Description</discount_description>
                <customer_balance_amount>Customer Balance</customer_balance_amount>
                <base_customer_balance_amount>Base Customer Balance</base_customer_balance_amount>
                <_gift_message>Gift Message</_gift_message>
                <_order_comments>Order Comments</_order_comments>
                <customer_id>Customer ID</customer_id>
                <multifees>Extra fees</multifees>
            </attributes>
            <routes>
                <route_entity>
                    <route>/mycompany/orders/:order_id</route>
                    <action_type>entity</action_type>
                </route_entity>
            </routes>
            <force_attributes>
                <admin>
                    <payment_method>1</payment_method>
                    <addresses>1</addresses>
                    <order_items>1</order_items>
                    <gift_message_from>1</gift_message_from>
                    <gift_message_to>1</gift_message_to>
                    <gift_message_body>1</gift_message_body>
                    <order_comments>1</order_comments>
                    <tax_name>1</tax_name>
                    <tax_rate>1</tax_rate>
                </admin>
            </force_attributes>
            <versions>1</versions>
        </order>
        <order_item translate="title" module="api2">
            <group>sales_order</group>
            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
            <model>sales/api2_order_item</model>
            <working_model>sales/order_item</working_model>
            <title>Order Items</title>
            <privileges>
                <admin>
                    <retrieve>1</retrieve>
                </admin>
                <customer>
                    <retrieve>1</retrieve>
                </customer>
            </privileges>
            <attributes translate="item_id name parent_item_id sku price price_incl_tax qty_ordered qty_invoiced qty_shipped qty_canceled qty_refunded row_total row_total_incl_tax base_price original_price base_original_price base_price_incl_tax tax_percent tax_amount base_tax_amount discount_amount base_discount_amount base_row_total base_row_total_incl_tax" module="api2">
                <item_id>Order Item ID</item_id>
                <name>Product and Custom Options Name</name>
                <parent_item_id>Parent Order Item ID</parent_item_id>
                <sku>SKU</sku>
                <price>Price</price>
                <price_incl_tax>Price Including Tax</price_incl_tax>
                <qty_ordered>Ordered Qty</qty_ordered>
                <qty_invoiced>Invoiced Qty</qty_invoiced>
                <qty_shipped>Shipped Qty</qty_shipped>
                <qty_canceled>Canceled Qty</qty_canceled>
                <qty_refunded>Refunded Qty</qty_refunded>
                <row_total>Item Subtotal</row_total>
                <row_total_incl_tax>Item Subtotal Including Tax</row_total_incl_tax>
                <base_price>Base Price</base_price>
                <original_price>Original Price</original_price>
                <base_original_price>Base Original Price</base_original_price>
                <base_price_incl_tax>Base Price Including Tax</base_price_incl_tax>
                <tax_percent>Tax Percent</tax_percent>
                <tax_amount>Tax Amount</tax_amount>
                <base_tax_amount>Base Tax Amount</base_tax_amount>
                <discount_amount>Discount Amount</discount_amount>
                <base_discount_amount>Base Discount Amount</base_discount_amount>
                <base_row_total>Base Item Subtotal</base_row_total>
                <base_row_total_incl_tax>Base Item Subtotal Including Tax</base_row_total_incl_tax>
            </attributes>
            <include_attributes>
                <customer>
                    <read>
                        <item_id>1</item_id>
                        <name>1</name>
                        <parent_item_id>1</parent_item_id>
                        <sku>1</sku>
                        <price>1</price>
                        <price_incl_tax>1</price_incl_tax>
                        <qty_ordered>1</qty_ordered>
                        <qty_invoiced>1</qty_invoiced>
                        <qty_shipped>1</qty_shipped>
                        <qty_canceled>1</qty_canceled>
                        <qty_refunded>1</qty_refunded>
                        <row_total>1</row_total>
                        <row_total_incl_tax>1</row_total_incl_tax>
                    </read>
                </customer>
            </include_attributes>
            <routes>
                <route_collection>
                    <route>/orders/:id/items</route>
                    <action_type>collection</action_type>
                </route_collection>
            </routes>
            <versions>1</versions>
        </order_item>
        <order_address translate="title" module="api2">
            <group>sales_order</group>
            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
            <model>sales/api2_order_address</model>
            <working_model>sales/order_address</working_model>
            <title>Order Addresses</title>
            <privileges>
                <admin>
                    <retrieve>1</retrieve>
                </admin>
                <customer>
                    <retrieve>1</retrieve>
                </customer>
            </privileges>
            <routes>
                <route_entity>
                    <route>/orders/:order_id/addresses/:address_type</route>
                    <action_type>entity</action_type>
                </route_entity>
                <route_collection>
                    <route>/orders/:order_id/addresses</route>
                    <action_type>collection</action_type>
                </route_collection>
            </routes>
            <versions>1</versions>
            <attributes translate="lastname firstname middlename prefix suffix company street city region postcode country_id telephone address_type email" module="api2">
                <lastname>Customer Last Name</lastname>
                <firstname>Customer First Name</firstname>
                <middlename>Customer Middle Name</middlename>
                <prefix>Customer Prefix</prefix>
                <suffix>Customer Suffix</suffix>
                <company>Company</company>
                <street>Street</street>
                <city>City</city>
                <region>State</region>
                <postcode>ZIP/Postal Code</postcode>
                <country_id>Country</country_id>
                <telephone>Phone Number</telephone>
                <address_type>Address Type</address_type>
                <email>Email</email>
            </attributes>
        </order_address>
        <order_comment translate="title" module="api2">
            <group>sales_order</group>
            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
            <model>sales/api2_order_comment</model>
            <working_model>sales/order_status_history</working_model>
            <title>Order Comments</title>
            <privileges>
                <admin>
                    <retrieve>1</retrieve>
                </admin>
                <customer>
                    <retrieve>1</retrieve>
                </customer>
            </privileges>
            <force_attributes>
                <admin>
                    <created_at>1</created_at>
                    <comment>1</comment>
                    <is_customer_notified>1</is_customer_notified>
                    <is_visible_on_front>1</is_visible_on_front>
                    <status>1</status>
                </admin>
                <customer>
                    <created_at>1</created_at>
                    <comment>1</comment>
                </customer>
            </force_attributes>
            <routes>
                <route_collection>
                    <route>/orders/:id/comments</route>
                    <action_type>collection</action_type>
                </route_collection>
            </routes>
            <versions>1</versions>
        </order_comment>
    </resources>
</api2>
</config>
```

I am only concerned with the Order object. I want to keep using the other built-in objects like Order Items, Customer Addresses, Order Comments as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This api2.xml works:

```
<config>
<api2>
    <resource_groups>
        <mymodule translate="title" module="mymodule">
            <title>MyCompany Order API</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        </mymodule>
    </resource_groups>
    <resources>
        <mymodule translate="title" module="mymodule">
            <group>mymodule</group>
            <model>mymodule/api2_order</model>
            <title>Order with Extra Fees</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <privileges>
                <admin>
                    <retrieve>1</retrieve>
                </admin>
            </privileges>
            <attributes translate="entity_id increment_id created_at status shipping_description _payment_method base_currency_code store_currency_code store_name remote_ip store_to_order_rate subtotal subtotal_incl_tax discount_amount base_grand_total grand_total shipping_amount shipping_tax_amount shipping_incl_tax tax_amount _tax_name _tax_rate coupon_code base_discount_amount base_subtotal base_shipping_amount base_shipping_tax_amount base_tax_amount total_paid base_total_paid total_refunded base_total_refunded base_subtotal_incl_tax base_total_due total_due shipping_discount_amount base_shipping_discount_amount discount_description customer_balance_amount base_customer_balance_amount base_customer_balance_amount _gift_message _order_comments customer_id multifees" module="mymodule">
                <entity_id>Order ID (internal)</entity_id>
                <increment_id>Order ID</increment_id>
                <created_at>Order Date</created_at>
                <status>Order Status</status>
                <shipping_description>Shipping Method</shipping_description>
                <_payment_method>Payment Method</_payment_method>
                <base_currency_code>Base Currency</base_currency_code>
                <store_currency_code>Order Currency</store_currency_code>
                <store_name>Store Name</store_name>
                <remote_ip>Placed from IP</remote_ip>
                <store_to_order_rate>Store Currency to Order Currency Rate</store_to_order_rate>
                <subtotal>Subtotal</subtotal>
                <subtotal_incl_tax>Subtotal Including Tax</subtotal_incl_tax>
                <discount_amount>Discount</discount_amount>
                <base_grand_total>Grand Total to Be Charged</base_grand_total>
                <grand_total>Grand Total</grand_total>
                <shipping_amount>Shipping Amount</shipping_amount>
                <shipping_tax_amount>Shipping Including Tax</shipping_tax_amount>
                <shipping_incl_tax>Shipping Tax</shipping_incl_tax>
                <tax_amount>Tax Amount</tax_amount>
                <_tax_name>Tax Name</_tax_name>
                <_tax_rate>Tax Rate</_tax_rate>
                <coupon_code>Coupon Code</coupon_code>
                <base_discount_amount>Base Discount</base_discount_amount>
                <base_subtotal>Base Subtotal</base_subtotal>
                <base_shipping_amount>Base Shipping</base_shipping_amount>
                <base_shipping_tax_amount>Base Shipping Tax</base_shipping_tax_amount>
                <base_tax_amount>Base Tax Amount</base_tax_amount>
                <total_paid>Total Paid</total_paid>
                <base_total_paid>Base Total Paid</base_total_paid>
                <total_refunded>Total Refunded</total_refunded>
                <base_total_refunded>Base Total Refunded</base_total_refunded>
                <base_subtotal_incl_tax>Base Subtotal Including Tax</base_subtotal_incl_tax>
                <base_total_due>Base Total Due</base_total_due>
                <total_due>Total Due</total_due>
                <shipping_discount_amount>Shipping Discount</shipping_discount_amount>
                <base_shipping_discount_amount>Base Shipping Discount</base_shipping_discount_amount>
                <discount_description>Discount Description</discount_description>
                <customer_balance_amount>Customer Balance</customer_balance_amount>
                <base_customer_balance_amount>Base Customer Balance</base_customer_balance_amount>
                <_gift_message>Gift Message</_gift_message>
                <_order_comments>Order Comments</_order_comments>
                <customer_id>Customer ID</customer_id>
                <multifees>Extra fees</multifees>
            </attributes>
            <routes>
                <route_entity>
                    <route>/mymodule/orders/:id</route>
                    <action_type>entity</action_type>
                </route_entity>
            </routes>
            <force_attributes>
                <admin>
                    <payment_method>1</payment_method>
                    <addresses>1</addresses>
                    <order_items>1</order_items>
                    <gift_message_from>1</gift_message_from>
                    <gift_message_to>1</gift_message_to>
                    <gift_message_body>1</gift_message_body>
                    <order_comments>1</order_comments>
                    <tax_name>1</tax_name>
                    <tax_rate>1</tax_rate>
                </admin>
            </force_attributes>
            <versions>1</versions>
        </mymodule>
    </resources>
</api2>
</config>
```

And the config.xml should look like:

```
<config>
    <global>
    ...
        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model</class>
            </mymodule>
        </models>
    ...
    </global>
 </config>
```